# Different installer variations of single Java version

Tags: java, installer

Can anybody explain to me the difference between jre-6u20-Windows-i586-s.exe (downloaded from www.java.com) and jre-6u20-Windows-i586.exe (java.sun.com)? what does -s mean?

And also what are exactly for these?

jre-6u20-Windows-i586-iftw-rv.exe

jre-6u20-Windows-i586-iftw-k.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "s" version offers optional components like OpenOffice and toolbars.

Windows Online Installation (jre-6u20-windows-i586-iftw-rv.exe)
Windows Kernel Installation (jre-6u20-windows-i586-iftw-k.exe)